# Laravel event SocialiteWasCalled fired once every minute

Tags: laravel

I am using `Laravel Telescope` to better debug my website. Doing so I found that in the *Events* tab, I could see a lot of `SocialiteWasCalled`-entries. Inspecting them further, it seems that almost all of them were triggered by my cron-server running `Laravel Horizon`.

They are triggered exactly once every minute, meaning it is the `php artisan schedule:run`-command. I've tried locally running that command, and it does generate a new event-entry in `Telescope`, *even when `schedule()` is empty*.

Here is the *Event Data*:

```
{
app: {
  class: "Illuminate\Foundation\Application",
  properties: {
  contextual: {
    Laravel\Telescope\Storage\DatabaseEntriesRepository: {
      $connection: "mysql"
    }
  }
}
},
configRetriever: {
  class: "SocialiteProviders\Manager\Helpers\ConfigRetriever",
  properties: [
  ]
},
spoofedConfig: {
  client_id: "spoofed_client_id",
  client_secret: "spoofed_client_secret",
  redirect: "spoofed_redirect"
}
}
```

In my `EventServiceProvider` i have registered the `SocialiteWasCalled` like this.

```
protected $listen = [
    SocialiteWasCalled::class => [
        InstagramExtendSocialite::class,
    ],
];
```

> Why is `SocialiteWasCalled` being called by the scheduler, and is it normal?